# Handling delayed execution of a program in java

Tags: java

I am running an `.exe` file from my program and it is taking certain time for the same.The output from this command is used in the following statements for further processing. The output is a boolean variable. But the program is returning `false` immediately, but in fact the command is still in execution and is taking certain time. Because of the false value the subsequent statements is throwing an error. How do i handle this situation.
The `return_var = exec(pagecmd)` is the executing statement.

```
boolean return_var = false;
if("true".equals(getConfig("splitmode", ""))){
    System.out.println("Inside splitmode if**********************");
    String pagecmd = command.replace("%", page);
    pagecmd = pagecmd + " -p " + page;
    File f = new File(swfFilePath); 
    System.out.println("The swffile inside splitmode block exists is -----"+f.exists());
    System.out.println("The pagecmd is -----"+pagecmd);
    if(!f.exists()){
        return_var = exec(pagecmd);
        System.out.println("The return_var inside splitmode is----"+return_var);
        if(return_var) {                    
            strResult=doc;                       
        }else{                      
            strResult = "Error converting document, make sure the conversion tool is installed and that correct user permissions are applied to the SWF Path directory" + 
                        getDocUrl();
        }
```

Comment: And your `exec(..)` method does what?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you are finally using [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) inside your `exec()` method, you can use the [`waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method of the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object which is returned from `Runtime.exec()` to wait until the execution has finished:

```
...
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pagecmd);
int result = p.waitFor();
...
```

The return value from `waitFor()` is the exit code of the sub process.

If you actually need to **read** output from the sub process which the sub process is writing to its `stderr` or `stdout` channel, you need to use `Process.getInputStream()` (Note: **not** `getOutputStream()`) and `Process.getErrorStream()` and read the sub processes output from these streams. Then, check the return values from the stream's `read()` methods to check if the sub process has terminated (or at least closed its output streams) instead of using `waitFor()`.

Also, for these kind of problems, you should consider using the [Apache commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) library.

Alternatively, you might want to check the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

Comment: Hi Andreas -  p.waitFor() did the trick and the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In conjuction with waitFor() suggested by Andreas, you may also need to use getInputStream of Process object returned by exec() to retrieve the data written by the program you are executing.